# Why can't I instantiate an mbed USB wrapper class on android

Tags: java, android, mbed

I followed this direction [here](http://mbed.org/cookbook/mbed-with-Android-ADK) and added the two USB wrapper the author created (AdkPort and Ringbuffer)

[image]

Moving cursor on it says "class" or "interface" expected.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: It looks like you are declaring mbed outside a class...

Comment: The link you point to shows a code snippet... what may not be evident to you is that "private AdkPort mbed;" is inside an Activity, which is a class.

Comment: @Leco, that did it. Thanks, I'll accept that as an answer

Comment: Glad I could help. I will post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring mbed outside a class.

The link you point to shows the following code snippet:

```
private AdkPort mbed;
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ...
            mbed = new AdkPort(this);
            Thread thread = new Thread(mbed);
            thread.start();
            mbed.attachOnNew(new AdkPort.MessageNotifier(){ 
        @Override
        public void onNew()
        {
            byte[] in = mbed.readB();
                            // Do something with the data
                    }
            });
            ...
   }
```

What may not be evident to you is that, in the above snippet, "private AdkPort mbed;" is inside an Activity, which is a class.